# Python/Pandas - Combining groupby mean and min

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mean, min

What's the syntax for combining `mean` and a `min` on a dataframe? I want to group by 2 columns, calculate the mean within a group for `col3` and keep the `min` value of `col4`. Would something like

`groupeddf = nongrouped.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], as_index=False).mean().min('col4')`

work? If not, what's the correct syntax? Thank you!

**EDIT**

Okay, so the question wasn't quite clear without an example. I'll update it now. Also changes in text above.

I have:

```
ungrouped
col1 col2 col3 col4
1    2    3    4
1    2    4    1
2    4    2    1
2    4    1    3
2    3    1    3
```

Wanted output is grouped by columns 1-2, mean for column 3 (and actually some more columns on the data, this is simplified) and the minimum of col4:

```
grouped
col1 col2 col3 col4
1    2    3.5  1
2    4    1.5  1
2    3    1    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need first `mean` and then `min` of column `col4`:

```
min_val = nongrouped.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], as_index=False).mean()['col4'].min()
```

or `min` of `Series`:

```
min_val = nongrouped.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])['col4'].mean().min()
```

Sample:

```
nongrouped = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,1,3],
                   'col2':[1,1,6],
                   'col3':[1,1,9],
                   'col4':[1,3,5]})

print (nongrouped)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     1     1     1
1     1     1     1     3
2     3     6     9     5

print (nongrouped.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])['col4'].mean())
1     1     1       2
3     6     9       5
Name: col4, dtype: int64

min_val = nongrouped.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])['col4'].mean().min()
print (min_val)
2
```

EDIT:

You need [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
groupeddf = nongrouped.groupby(['col1', 'col2'], sort=False)
                      .agg({'col3':'mean','col4':'min'})
                      .reset_index()
                      .reindex(columns=nongrouped.columns)
print (groupeddf)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     2   3.5     1
1     2     4   1.5     1
2     2     3   1.0     3
```

Comment: Yes, better is if some samples in question.

Comment: Almost 100k! :D

Comment: and it is my name-day present, because my name is Joe ;)

Comment: Yes, I think too ;)

Comment: And there we go! Congrats!

Comment: I'm sorry guys, the question wasn't really straightforward I guess. I updated it.

Comment: So I don't just need a value, I'd need a grouped dataframe, where the groupby produces means for certain columns and a mininmum for another.